# Can't display data after fetch

Tags: reactjs, axios, material-ui

I'm trying to get a data from an REST endpoint through axios and then render them in my app.js component and after that provide them to the whole app by using context API:

axios.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'api_endpoint'
});


export default instance;
```

app.js

```
import Context from './context'

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      comp: []
    }
  };
async componentDidMount() {
     await instance.get('')
      .then(res => {
          const data = JSON.stringify(res.data.data)
          this.setState({comp: data});
          console.table('componentDidMount', data); // here I can log the data
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      });

  }

 render () {
    return (

      <Context.Provider 
        value={{
          comp: this.state.comp
        }}>
      </comp.Provider>

    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

children.js

```
import Context from '../../context'

class Children extends Component { 
    render () {
        const { classes } = this.props;
        return (
          <Context.Consumer>
                    {context => (
                  <Paper className={classes.root}>
                    <Table className={classes.table}>
                      <TableHead>
                        <TableRow>
                          <CustomTableCell>comp_id</CustomTableCell>
                          <CustomTableCell align="right">comp_name</CustomTableCell>
                          <CustomTableCell align="right">comp_price</CustomTableCell>
                          <CustomTableCell align="right">comp_log_usd</CustomTableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                      </TableHead>

                      <TableBody>
                        {Object.entries(context.comp).forEach(([key, value]) => (
                          <TableRow className={classes.row} key={value.id}>
                          <CustomTableCell component="th" scope="row">
                            {value.id}
                          </CustomTableCell>
                          <CustomTableCell align="right">{value.name}</CustomTableCell>
                          <CustomTableCell align="right">{value.price}</CustomTableCell>
                          <CustomTableCell align="right">{value.log.usd}</CustomTableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                        ))}
                      </TableBody>
                    </Table>
                  </Paper>
              )}
            </Context.Consumer>
        );
    }
```

The first problem is that when I try to render it like that it shows that my "log" property despite that I logged it and tested it and it works fine, it shows this error: "Cannot read property 'log' of undefined"

second issue is that when I remove CustomTableCell which have this property then it loads my data outside of the table and it gives me the whole array of objects outside of my table.

So, any help will be appreciated here.

Comment: share error message for first issue.

Answer (score 0):

If your going to use async functions then don't use .then() it makes it too hard to track in my opinion. I have never used async on component did mount and this answer assumes that that's fine but try this

```
 async componentDidMount() {
  try{
   let response = await instance.get('')
   const data = JSON.stringify(response.data.data)
   this.setState({comp: data});
   console.table('componentDidMount', data); // here I can log the data
  }
  catch(error){console.log(error);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but the problem now is that I can't find my data in my children.js but I can log them in my app.js and I did console.log for my data when I wanted to access to some properties and it worked fine for me but not when I want to display them in my component

Comment: Right that's because you have a scope problem , I think this will fix it.

Comment: or you can try just getting rid of keywords async/await because there not needed the way you have it set up.

Comment: I already fixed getting data from app.js to children.js but I can't iterate them through my material-ui table and it render them outside of my table in a table contain a JSON objects

Comment: have you tried using .map() instead of for each that may be the problem