# React Hooks Not Allowing Me to Display Single Objects After Fetch Call

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, fetch, react-hooks

I am calling a standard JSON file using fetch on a React Hooks project.
*(I'm mocking a server using JSON-Server to read the local json file)*

In my main function, I'm calling a variable and a function, like any normal React Hook, and setting it to an empty array because I'm calling API data using fetch.

```
let [items, setItems] = useState([]);
```

Then I'm making my actual fetch call to my mock server

```
    const fetchItems = async () => {
        const url = "http://localhost:3002/learn";
        const response = await fetch(url);
        items = await response.json();
        setItems(items);
        console.log(items[0].title);
    }
```

The `console.log(items[0].title)` does in fact return the correct value.

If I wanted to display all results, the following would even work.

```
{items.map((item) => 
   <img src={item.source} alt={item.title} title={item.title}  className="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" />
)}
```

However, once I want to display a single value in my return, I get an error message saying:
*"TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined"*
The code that I'm using, just to test at first is the same exact thing as my `console.log` from before.

```
<img src={items[0].source} alt={items[0].title} title={items[0].title}  className="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" />
```

**Am I missing a major step that allows me to use the fetched info in my return?**

If I were to hard-code my JSON data on the same component, it would work. I feel like it has something to do with fetch.
I was looking at this question, and it's similar, but not the same thing. I'm also using hooks and also not axios. [Can't display data after fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56050951/cant-display-data-after-fetch)

UPDATE:
The JSON file looks something like this:

```
{
    "learn": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Angular JS",
        "source": "./images/logo-angular-js.png"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Firebase",
        "source": "./images/logo-firebase.png"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "GraphQL",
        "source": "./images/logo-graphql.png"
      }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please share the `items` array. What it looks like? Is there anything called `source`?

Comment: `items = await response.json();` don't do this. Only set state using the state setter. Do not mutate state directly.

Comment: The only reason I did that was because it was saying my result was undefined if I did it like `let items = await response.json();`

Comment: Try ``items = (await response.json()).learn;`` in your ``fetchItems`` call.

Comment: If that's not helping, try logging the entire ``items`` object in the fetch call and posting its contents here. It might be that the array contains at least one null value, apart from the first item that you are currently logging.

Comment: Lukas, the .learn comes back undefined, and if I move the entire render into the fetch call, I get *Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your first render, `items` has a length of 0, so `items[0]` is going to be `undefined`. You're likely trying to render before that first item has loaded.

Check if `items[0]` is defined before trying to access `items[0].source` and the like.

```
function YourComponent() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchItems();
  }, []);

  const fetchItems = async () => {
    const url = "http://localhost:3002/learn";
    const response = await fetch(url);
    items = await response.json();
    setItems(items);
    console.log(items[0].title);
  }

  if (!items.length) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <img 
      src={items[0].source}
      alt={items[0].title}
      title={items[0].title}
      className="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" /> 
  );
}
```

On the first render, this will cause nothing to be output. After the `setItems` call is made, the component will re-render, and this time (if there were items being set), it'll render your item.

Comment: Damn, this does work. Ok, just so I know what's going on. If making a fetch call, the component renders first, then on the old componentDidMount(useEffect), the fetch call happens, which re-renders. That would make sense for why hard coded objects would work right away and not fetched info. Hard coded info is rendered immediately with the original render. This really feels like a benchmark. Thank you so much. I was really losing faith in StackOverflow.

Comment: Would you have an explanation as to why .map works then? Is there a built-in continue feature in .map?

Comment: It's because doing a `map` over an empty array makes another empty array, and rendering an empty array of elements works has the effect of not rendering anything.